# Hide div using JQuery - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a div which is displayed on page when it loads. I added a button into this div and I want that when user clicks on this button it will hide the div using JQuery.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="tabs" class="news1">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Track</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">History</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    <table id="currentloc_table">
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <!--th>Latitude</th>
    <th>Longitude</th-->
    <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>

    <button>hide</button>

</div>
```

Here is the script in  tag on same page:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        });

        $("button").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
</script>
```

But due to some reason it does not work. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: make sure script inside $(document).ready();

Comment: it's working here http://jsfiddle.net/wQ3nn/

Comment: @Sachin Irrelevant. If you use the `onLoad` mode in jsFiddle then it's essentially a simulated `$(document).ready()`. Try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/wQ3nn/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your .click binding inside of your $(function () {}). Like this.

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        $("button").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    });
```

In jQuery $(function () {}) is a shorthand for $(document).ready(function () {}) which is called when all the HTML for the page is loaded. When you put a binding outside of this ready call, it attempts to bind before the HTML is loaded. If the HTML isn't loaded, no elements exist to bind to, so then no bindings are applied! By moving it inside of the ready (or your short-hand ready), we ensure that all elements are loaded and capable of being bound to properly.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put your code below:

```
$("button").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Inside the `$(function() {}` like:

```
$(function () {

    // Call the jQuery tabs
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    // Call button click event here
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

This would specify the click event to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.